# Ошибка применения декоратора

Tags: python, flask, декоратор

В роутингах постоянно прописывал:

```
print('--- NAME_ROUTING ---')
print_request(request)
```

где:

- NAME_ROUTING - это имя ротинга (его вписывал постоянно сам)
- print_request - это печать того, что пришло в request (все POST, GET, JSON и т.д.)

Решил закинуть это в декоратор:

```
def print_information(func):
    def wraper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('<--| ' + func.__name__ + ' |-->')
        print_request(request)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wraper
```

Кинул его перед первым роутингом:

```
@app.route('/sample_router')
@print_information
def sample_router():
    return jsonify({
        'response': 'my super response'
    })
```

В итоге, сделал запрос и все отработало: напечаталось имя **sample_router**

Но, если создать 2ой роутер и кинуть туда декоратор:

```
@app.route('/sample_router')
@print_information
def sample_router():
    return jsonify({
        'response': 'my super response'
    })

@app.route('/sample_router2')
@print_information
def sample_router2():
    return jsonify({
        'response2': 'my super response2'
    })
```

Вылетит ошибка:

> raise AssertionError(
> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wraper

Что не так сделал?

Comment: У вас получилось две вьюхи с одинаковым именем wraper. Перед враперами воткните `@functools.wraps(func)`